# Defining an array within an if statement in java

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement

I've tried both declaring it within the switch statement...

```
    switch (c)
    {
        case 0: int[] statList = {5,1,3,3,1,2}; break;
        case 1: int[] statList = {3,1,5,2,1,3}; break;
        case 2: int[] statList = {1,5,3,1,3,2}; break;
        case 3: int[] statList = {3,1,2,5,3,1}; break;
        case 4: int[] statList = {3,2,3,1,1,5}; break;
        case 5: int[] statList = {1,3,2,3,5,1}; break;
        case 6: int[] statList = {4,4,1,1,1,4}; break;
        default: int[] statList = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
    }
```

and outside the switch statement...

```
    int[] statList = new int[6];
    switch (c)
    {
        case 0: statList = {5,1,3,3,1,2}; break;
        case 1: statList = {3,1,5,2,1,3}; break;
        case 2: statList = {1,5,3,1,3,2}; break;
        case 3: statList = {3,1,2,5,3,1}; break;
        case 4: statList = {3,2,3,1,1,5}; break;
        case 5: statList = {1,3,2,3,5,1}; break;
        case 6: statList = {4,4,1,1,1,4}; break;
        default statList = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
    }
```

but both are giving me an error, is there an easy way to do this without using a loop or by defining each value one by one?  Because that would somewhat defeat the purpose of me using the array in the first place.

Comment: The fact that it is a `switch` doesn't matter (except for the scope, but you seem to have figured that out already).

Comment: Use `new int[]{...}`.